# How to make textarea autogrow using ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, autogrow

How can I make the `TextArea` [autogrow](https://github.com/ultimatedelman/autogrow) plugin work with ember.js? It does not seem to work with `Ember.TextArea`.

I tried this (coffeescript):

```
  App.TextField = Ember.TextArea.extend
    didInsertElement: ->
      opts =
        animate: false
        cloneClass: 'faketextarea'
      @$().autogrow(opts)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the way Ember gets `this.$()` for the view that doesn't play nicely with the autogrow plugin, causing autogrow to not correctly listen for events on the `TextArea`. Explicitly creating the selector using the `elementId` of the view allows your example to work.

I'm using Ember 1.0.0-PRE.4

Example: http://jsbin.com/adedag/8/edit

```
App.TextField = Ember.TextArea.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    opts = {
      animate: false,
      cloneClass: 'faketextarea'
    }
    $('#'+this.get('elementId')).autogrow(opts);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Bower, consider this alternative also: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.0",
    "ember": "1.2.0-beta.4",
    "ember-data-shim": "v1.0.0-beta.3",
    "handlebars": "1.1.2",
    "jquery-autosize":""
},
```

Then

```
App.AutosizeTextArea = Ember.TextArea.extend({
didInsertElement: function() {
    $('#'+this.get('elementId')).autosize();
}
```

});

And

```
{{view App.AutosizeTextArea value=notes}}
```

Comment: Nice, this one supports event triggering, which is pretty usefull since we have to deal with two-way bindings! Two others I found didn't support events, and only listen to the keyUp-event.